# How to build a route that has a `#` in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

How can you build a route with a hashtag (`#`) in it? I created the route

```
get 'authors/#/:id' => 'authors#show
```

But this generates the route

```
GET    /authors/%23/:id(.:format)
```

So it has `%23` where the `#` should be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `#` in a URL on the server, it's call a [Fragment Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and is a local in-page anchor which a browser will never send to the server.

#### Update

OP added information in comment re client-side routing.

Yes, while this makes no sense on the server-side of your app, you can absolutely have client-side routes with hashes in them. Modern browsers (HTML5 support) even have a `hashchange` event that you can bind to, although because older browsers don't support that then you will generally use a `hashchange` plugin for jQuery, or perhaps Angular supports this itself.

The idea is that basically the browser can detect the URL change and because the `#` change never triggers a request to the server then this is a convenient way to trigger changes in your client-side app without triggering a server request.

#### Another Update

After another comment from OP...

There is nothing at all for you to do on the server side. If your front-end guy wants to use a `#`-based URL like `/authors#123` to trigger a client-side load of that author then his **JS would be listening** for that `hashchange` and then he would make **a regular, non-hash-containing, request to the server** like `GET /authors/123.json` and then would use the response from that to update the HTML of the loaded page.

Comment: Thanks. I got the request from someone developing a front end in Javascript/Angularjs. He said that with such a URL, it would make it easier for the front end to use (meaning easier to determine which author to render??). Does this perhaps ring a bell, that he was perhaps talking about a different way of using `#` than I present in my post?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. How would the server-side accommodate this behavior? Because how I understand it, he wanted me at the back end to include a such a route. This would then be the route to the view that includes the API/javascript code. But like you said, it doesn't seem possible to create such a route in `route.rb`.